# Google analytics: previous url in click-through path

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to find out the previous url to the given url and get into a mess on this.

I'm currently in analytics view `Behavior→all pages`. The first column is `page`. My tries are to add a secondary dimonesion, and here what i get:

- `Destination Page` - there i get the same url, as in `page`,
- `Next Page Path` - same thing, same url, as in `page`,
- `Second Page` - looks always like next higher directory. If `Page` in the first column is /1/2/3/, `Second Page` is /1/2/, if `Page` is /1/2/, `Second Page` is /1/.

My thoughts - something is wrong in analytics setup, or i just how things i'm lookig for are working.

Could somebody point me into the right direction? I need to know **what is the next url, which was visited after the given url** (given = primary page url in the view).

Answer (score 2):

In Behavior->Overview, click on the page that you want to view more details on. Then click Secondary Dimension->Behavior->Previous Page Path

[image: Google Analytics - Previous page path]

Answer (score 0):

Above the chart, look for it where it has 2 tabs one labelled Explorer, the other Navigation Summary. Change it so you're looking at the Navigation Summary. There you'll see a previous and next page report.

Comment: This is the view only for one url, which is `current selection` and it needs to be selected manually. An export doesn't deliver the data list too - only for the currently selected url. This view isn't usable. Is there a possibility to see the same but as the secondary dimension?